# <audio> tag unusual behavior in android chrome

Tags: android, html, html5-audio, progressive-download

I have

```
<audio src="SOURCE1" />
```

playing perfectly in Android Browser.  But when I

```
 wget SOURCE1
```

and then use

```
<audio src="MYSERVER/SAME_MP3" />
```

it is not recognized in android chrome! I've no idea what is going wrong.

Is it the way the my-server is configured? The response headers of both the servers look alike. Just that my server is connecting on https.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: so `<audio src="MYSERVER/SAME_MP3" />` works fine until you wget the file?

Comment: sorry, I meant `SOURCE 1`  is an external source - `http://example.com/source1` .  So, the answer is a No. 

Also, as it turns out,it must be a server configuration problem (delivering audio?)

I tried doing the same thing on another server of mine with `http` and `not https` , but it didn't work either. No luck with my CDN too.

But I've no idea which configuration is screwed up. :(

Answer (score 0):

How about Chrome for Windows or Mac? Does it handle this in the correct way? If it's not, you can see the HTTP(S) connection in the debug console.

If it's Chrome for Android only, try this remote debugger. It also shows the same thing: http://code.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging.html

Comment: Yes, chrome for windows/mac handles this the correct way & it happens only for Android.

Well, another interesting thing that I encountered is , if you give the source as `http://wikipedia.org/some_ogg_file.ogg` , it works perfectly but if you give the source as `https://wikipedia.org/some_ogg_file.ogg`  - it doesn't ! crazy!

Comment: It must be some server configuration error. I tried out downloading the same file on another server of mine with http , but it didn't work either. I tried using my CDN, no use.